# How did Draco master the Elder wand

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

How did Draco master the Elder wand seeing as the **Elder wand changes its allegiance only to those people who are brave enough to face the death**? This seems to be contradictory because Draco is portrayed as a weak and timid character in the books who is far from brave. So how did he come to master the Elder wand?

Comment: `...since the Elder wand changes its allegiance only to those people who are brave enough to face the death` Elder Wand changes it's allegiance to the person who can defeat the current owner in battle

Comment: I  think I read it on Pottermore.

Comment: @HashirOmer - quote?

Comment: Also, technically speaking, anyone who challenges Harry Potter to a wizarding duel; AND/or flies a broom 100s feet off the ground and follows another seeker into a Wronsky feint, isn't exactly "timid" or "not brave". And this comes from someone for whom Draco is the least favorite character in the entire series

Answer (score 6):

Elder Wand does not change it's allegiance based on who is braver. It changes allegiance to the person who defeats the current owner. Since Draco disarmed Dumbledore at the Astronomy Tower when he flew in, this counted as Dumbledore being defeated at the hands of Draco, and the Elder Wand switched it's allegiance to him.

PS: In fact, most wands change allegiance towards the one who defeated the current owner

> “I took this wand from Draco Malfoy by force,” said Harry. “Can I use
>   it safely?”    “I think so. Subtle laws govern wand ownership, but the
>   conquered wand will  usually bend its will to its new master.”    “So
>   I should use this one?” said Ron, pulling Wormtail’s wand out of his
>   pocket  and handing it to Ollivander.    “Chestnut and dragon
>   heartstring. Nine-and-a-quarter inches. Brittle. I was forced  to make
>   this shortly after my kidnapping, for Peter Pettigrew. Yes, if you won
>   it, it is  more likely to do your bidding, and do it well, than
>   another wand.”

Answer (score 1):

Draco Malfoy was brave enough to face and disarm an Elder Wand wielder who was one of greatest wizards of all time. Elder Wand didn't have entire history of Draco, but it had this one.

Comment: Well, Dumbledore gave him a chance of coming to the right side but he was mortally afraid which means he was timid

Comment: In that event he was forced to, and he was too weak to kill Dumbledore...

Comment: @HashirOmer Canon never displayed level of sentience of Elder Wand. And, without knowing the background details, anyone can say Draco was brave.